# Is it possible alert when an element is loaded with jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Here's the example I'm working with, I'm trying to get an alert when the element is loaded in to the page with jquery .load, but can't seem to get it right, any suggestions? is this possible?

http://jsfiddle.net/ZhsBR/2/

html:

```
<div id="nav1">click to load content</div>
<div id="target"></div>
```

js:

```
$("#nav1").click(function() {
    $('#target').load('http://fiddle.jshell.net/user/login/ #content > *');
});

$("#pageContainer").ready(function() {
    alert("dynamic content has been loaded");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's called a callback, you must supply one in your `load()` function.

```
$('#target').load('http://fiddle.jshell.net/user/login/ #content > *', function(){
    //the request is complete
    alert("Dynamic Content Has Been loaded");
});
```

Comment: Actually, there is another way since jQuery 1.5, that is, using the returned promise.